# Переход между активностями

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. В приложении имеется две активности и между ними осуществляется переход в обоих направлениях. В обеих активностях используется один и тот же файл разметки `activity_main.xml`. Создаю так:

Первая активити (MainActivity.java):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Intent toOfflineMode = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OfflineActivity.class);
..//
```

И вторая активити (OfflineActivity.java):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Intent toOnlineMode = new Intent(OfflineActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
..//
```

И на соответствующие кнопки вешаю `startActivity(toOfflineMode);` и `startActivity(toOnlineMode);` соответственно. Так вот получается, что если перейти во вторую, а затем обратно в первую, те данные, которые были отображены в первой теряются. Складывается ощущение, что при каждом нажатии кнопки постоянно создается новый экземпляр активити(на экране новое окно выбегает справа налево). Если же нажать кнопку "назад" из второго активити первая возвращается(слева направо на экране) и данные на ней все остаются как положено. Подскажите пожалуйста, как осуществить переход между двумя этими активностями по кнопке без потери данных в обоих? Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Раз разметка одинаковая для обоих активити, то проще сделать все в одной активити. А для данных создать отдельный класс, и хранить данные в объектах этого класса. По кнопке уже подгружать данные в разметку из соответствующего объекта.

Comment: Одна активити это частный случай. Далее планируются новые активити с разными разметками...

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать фрагменты. В актвити хранить все данные, и подгружать различные фрагменты. Можно также создать синглтон класс, и в нем хранить данные каждой активити.

Comment: Почитал про синглтон, вроде даже получилось реализовать. Очень интересная вещь! Но все же это больше эдакое постоянное хранилище переменных. Хотелось бы полностью сохранять состояние активити. Если уйти на вторую активити, а затем вернуться на первую через `onBackPressed()` полное состояние первой сохраняется же как-то. Например есть `listview`, данные с него сохранить можно, а вот, скажем, положение прокрутки не сохранится. К тому же если `listview` загружает данные из интернета, то тоже проблемы.

Comment: Это на уровне ОС в стэке сохраняется активити. Только вот как последнюю активити завершаешь, она уничтожается. Может если только вручную как-нибудь с помощью `SaveInstanceState`, потому что  если выйти из активити с помощью метода `finish()` или `onBackPressed`, то когда запустишь снова активити, метод `onRestoreInstanceState` сам не запустится.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться методом [onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=ru).